# javafx window content is not painted on window raise in Windows7

Tags: windows, javafx, javafx-8, repaint

On window raise from Windows7 taskbar **window content is not painted** almost always, so that window contents look transparent. Window resize/maximize, hover over active element(such as button) or just click in window content area causes correct paint.

The issue is reproducible on some javafx windows while on others paint works always correctly.

Note: If I set focus on textfield (so that an I-cursor is blinking inside) - window is painted correctly after raise on next I-cursor blink.

**OS: Windows7, jre 1.8.0_05 (while on Ubuntu 12.04 it works correctly).**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are running into an instance of:

- [RT-31272 "Win: Window does not repaint after application collapse/expand via click icon on taskbar"](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31272).

This bug in Java 8u5 has been fixed in the [latest development release of Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

If your issue is not fixed in the latest development release, [create a new bug report](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report) in the JavaFX issue tracker.